# ¿Como soluciono el error de las variables int de java en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio, variables

Estoy inicializando un programa con el método Main y al momento de definir las variables me sale error sobre ellas, apenas estoy iniciado a programar Java en VSCode

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int x;
    x = 5;
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
}
```

Este es el error que me aparece al momento de definir la variable

```
The value of the local variable x is not usedJava(536870973)
```

Cuando intento corregirlo la única solución es eliminar la variable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: nombrandola de cualquier manera de arroja error?

Comment: Y si.. lo que mostras en la imagen es diferente a tu codigo.. y lo que mostras en la imagen tiene razon.. no usas nunca x... O sea, no es un error, es una advertencia para que no gaste memoria...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ya intenaste borrar el throws exception y agregarle el x=5; en la linea 4?